# Custom dictionary for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to create a custom dictionary for an edittext? In other words, can I create a custom list and have the edittext only suggest names from that list? I don't need it popping up useless word suggestions when the user is inputting specific names of people.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that's possible. Try looking for 'autocomplete dictionary' or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this link.

https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

They would have implemented content provider to provide a custom input to the quicksearch. You can try taking a similar approach where in you can make a query and update the result when a user enters each alphabet in your EditText box.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and provide your dictionary in the adapter.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html